# NSPredicate substitute key will output with quotes

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate, quotes

When I substitute the field name, I get a problem as follows

**Code**

```
NSString *fieldName = @"name";
NSPredicate *template = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"$key = nil"];
NSPredicate *pred = [template predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:@{@"key": fieldName}];
NSLog(@"%@", pred);
```

**Ouput**

```
"name" = nil
```

**Expected**

```
name = nil
```

**Problem**

name has quotes

How can get a predicate without quotes for key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to substitute with a key path expression instead of a string:

```
NSString *fieldName = @"name";
NSPredicate *template = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"$key = nil"];
NSExpression *keyPathExpr = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:fieldName];
NSPredicate *pred = [template predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:@{@"key": keyPathExpr}];
NSLog(@"%@", pred);
// name == nil
```

Comment: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K = nil",fieldName] may also work.